# OCLint got compile errors in html report file, but my project build success. WHY

Tags: objective-c, static-analysis, lint, oclint, oclint-json-compilation

[image: the html report result generated by oclint]

`xcodebuild -workspace ${myworkspace} -scheme ${myscheme} \
   -sdk iphonesimulator \
   -derivedDataPath ./build/derivedData \
   -configuration Debug \
   COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO  \
   | xcpretty -r json-compilation-database -o compile_commands.json`

I run the command line above to build my project, it build success, but when i run the command line below to generate oclint html report file, get 15 compiler errors.

`oclint-json-compilation-database -e Pods -- \
                   -extra-arg=-Wno-error=everything \
                   -report-type html \
                   -rc LONG_LINE=200 \
                   -rule MultipleUnaryOperator \
                   -max-priority-1=0 \
                   -max-priority-2=10 \
                   -max-priority-3=20 \
                   -o ./oclint_report.html`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
oclint-json-compilation-database <YOUR OPTIONS HERE> -- -extra-arg=-Wno-everything
```

as:

```
oclint-json-compilation-database -e Pods -- \
               -extra-arg=-Wno-error=everything \
               -report-type html \
               -rc LONG_LINE=200 \
               -rule MultipleUnaryOperator \
               -max-priority-1=0 \
               -max-priority-2=10 \
               -max-priority-3=20 \
               -extra-arg=-Wno-everything \
               -o ./oclint_report.html
```